# Selectable file formats at file open/save in MFC in Visual C++

Tags: mfc

My English is not perfect, sorry.

I am using Visual C++ 2019 Community, with MFC.

At `CFileDialog` class, I wish choose the file encoding: UTF-16 (little/big endian), UTF-8, ANSI, etc, at saving, with or without signature (2 or bytes what signs the encoding, at the begin of the file). This should be contacted to open/save button. In documentation of `CFileDialog`, I can add only separate buttons, not extending the open/save button like in Visual Studio, LibreOffice, etc. How can I do this? I am beginner with MFC, and desktop programs, but not beginner with C++. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try [CFileDialog::AddComboBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfiledialog-class?view=msvc-160#addcombobox) ?

Comment: At now I did not try this. The parameter is only on identifier. So, it seems, I must create this in resource view. But where? For example, on a dummy dialog? I can not create a button itself, only a dialog box, and a button onto the dialog box. I never do like this.

Comment: By the way, if I only want to open a lot of files in 1 time, I must rewrite the Open File routine, or can I set a setting, what does allow this?

Comment: There is a `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT` flag for it. Read the documentation or https://images-cdn.9gag.com/photo/5707699_700b.jpg

Comment: Yes, I know. But there is no place to write this. Handler of Open menu is built-in part of MFC. At the source code, CFileDialog is not happen. I added handler OnFileOpen(). This has not paramters, empty at now, and the open menu item manages well. So, I do not know to where I type OFN_ALLOWMULTISELCT.

Comment: I think you should learn basic C++ first. You can put the flag in the **constructor** call of your `CFileDialog` object.

Comment: CFileDialog does not happen in the source code! I have no any CFileDialog object! This, and calling document' class OnOpenDocument is built-in to MFC. I do not see this. I added OnFileOpen() handler to CMainFrm, this is empty, does not call base's handler, and the program works.

Comment: `CString sPath = PathWhereYouWantItToOpen(); CFileDialog dlg(TRUE, L"PDF", sPath, OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT, L"PDF Files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|"); if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK) { // do something with the files }`

Comment: @sergiol In 20 twenty years I have not realised `CFileDialog` had all of these customization functions!!!!!

Comment: @AndrewTruckle  Do you mean customization flags?

Comment: @sergiol AddComboBox etc. Thanks for making me aware of these methods.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle You're welcome. I just got lost in the communication as I was only reading the bottom messages.

Comment: @ZoltánHegedüs You can dynamically create a combobox. I recommend you to have a `CCombobox m_myCombo;` variable in your `CMyDialog` class and in its function `Create`, `OnInitDialog`, etc whatever you use to init your dialog, do `m_myCombo.Create()` and in that call, one of the parameters is the ID for the combobox. Pass something which is not already attributed and search Interner for `TN020`, to make the ID be in a valid range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments to your question you state:

> Yes, I know. But there is no place to write this. Handler of Open menu is built-in part of MFC. At the source code, `CFileDialog` is not happen. I added handler `OnFileOpen()`. This has not paramters, empty at now, and the open menu item manages well. So, I do not know to where I type `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELCT`.

If you look at [Technical Note 22](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn022-standard-commands-implementation?view=msvc-160) it mentions:

> `ID_FILE_OPEN` Opens an existing document.
>
> Note
>
> *You must connect this to your `CWinApp`-derived class's message map to
> enable this functionality.*
>
> `CWinApp::OnFileOpen` has a very simple implementation of calling
> `CWinApp::DoPromptFileName` followed by `CWinApp::OpenDocumentFile` with
> the file or path name of the file to open. The `CWinApp` implementation
> routine `DoPromptFileName` brings up the standard `FileOpen` dialog and
> fills it with the file extensions obtained from the current document
> templates.
>
> One common customization of `ID_FILE_OPEN` is to customize the `FileOpen`
> dialog or add additional file filters. The recommended way to
> customize this is to replace the default implementation with your own
> `FileOpen` dialog, and call `CWinApp::OpenDocumentFile` with the
> document's file or path name. There is no need to call the base class.

As you can see, it states:

> The `CWinApp` implementation
> routine `DoPromptFileName` brings up the standard `FileOpen` dialog and
> fills it with the file extensions obtained from the current document
> templates.

But `DoPromptFileName` seems to be an undocumented function. You can either:

- Debug into to MFC source code to see what it does and override it in your own app class,
- Continue to roll out your own `CWinApp::OnFileOpen` override which uses your own `CFileDialog`.

---

I suggest you also read up on [`CFileDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfiledialog-class?view=msvc-160#cfiledialog) constructor documentation because it will assist you for basic customization. However, it sounds to me you need to do what @sergiol said in the comments and display your own `CFileDialog` (using either approach previously described) and add your own combo with your encoding options. Then handle accordingly.

Please note that I have no experience with that level of customization but it should get you going.